# Multipoint discovery in glassfish

Tags: amazon-web-services, glassfish-4

In AWS, If I want to add new server instance of Glassfish dynamically where my EJB project is deployed.
In TomEE, we have multipoint discovery, where if I add new server it will automatically connect with the existing server cluster. Is any such thing available in Glassfish.

Comment: anyone done horizantal scaling in AWS for glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic discovery is not supported in GlassFish. You would need to write your own scripts to manage this by creating a new node in the DAS from the newly created EC2 instance and using the DAS to create a new instance on that machine. This can be made slightly easier by using an AMI which already has a known GlassFish configuration on it.

An alternative would be to use Payara Server, which is derived from GlassFish and adds [Hazelcast as a clustering method.](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/extended-documentation/hazelcast/enable-hazelcast.html)

To use Hazelcast for automatic discovery in AWS, you would need to supply your own `hazelcast.xml` config file to Payara Server which contains settings to use the TCP/IP joiner, since multicast is not supported in EC2. An alternative would be to use the [Hazelcast AWS plugin](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws) which can accept properties about your EC2 configuration and auto discover members that way.

Comment: can i use hazelcast with tomee

Comment: In theory, but not without a large amount of work. Payara Server has invested a lot of time and energy into getting Hazelcast to work as the clustering provider seamlessly, so I would imagine you would need detailed knowledge of the internals of TomEE to achieve anything similar with Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish provides the ability to auto-discover new instances in the cluster via Group Management Service (GMS)

```
$asadmin $das_host create-cluster --properties "GMS_DISCOVERY_URI_LIST=generate:GMS_LISTENER_PORT=$GMS_LISTENER_PORT" cluster1
```

You can find more details on this option at the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/create-cluster.htm#GSRFM00017).

However, you still need to find out how to connect your nodes to the cluster. We were able to automate this with containers: when a new node is provisioned it automatically connects to the cluster. We import DAS_HOST and DAS_PORT via env variables and mount SSH keys (that are required for the further remote management) via nfs volumes.

You can check how the final solution works in this article "[GlassFish and Payara Auto-Clustering](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/11/02/glassfish-payara-auto-clustering-cloud-hosting/)"